# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str error with using .format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a quick menu for fun however for the first option, as shown below in the code. It gives me some indices error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

However, some code that I made for a shopping list that uses a similar format works perfectly fine. Any ideas?

```
#Prototype Menu II

import sys

print ("""

Hello and WELCOME to the...
    __  ___                
   /  |/  /__  ____  __  __
  / /|_/ / _ \/ __ \/ / / /
 / /  / /  __/ / / / /_/ / 
/_/  /_/\___/_/ /_/\__,_/

Please enter one of the three following options!

1 - Entering Player Names
2 - Opening up a game
3 - Exit the Program

""")
choice = input("")

if choice == "1":
    players = []

    for count in range(2):
            name = input("Player Name:")
            players.append(name)

    for each in range(len(players)):
            print ("{0} ".format(players[name]))
```

Comment: retro retro retro I like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `each` as the list index not the `name` which is a string

```
    print ("{0} ".format(players[each]))
```

Instead of looping over the `range` of length of `players` you can loop over the `players` directly like this

```
for player in players:
    print ("{0} ".format(player))
```

Comment: and the OP would be better off looping directly over `players` anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup. Added that in the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank-you so much. Chose this as my answer.